# How do I save helm's interactive buffers?

Tags: emacs, save, elisp, emacs-helm

Emacs's helm is a very useful elisp package. But sometimes I want to save helm's interactive buffers in a file, such as `helm-for-files` buffer, `helm-M-x` buffer. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is `M-x write-file` although I suspect there is also `M-x helm-write-file`.

Comment: @ysakamoto In a regular setup, `write-file` is on `C-x C-w`.

Comment: But when I use helm's interactive function, the focus is on the minibuffer. So I cannot use `C-x C-w` or `M-x ...` command to save the interactive buffer

Comment: How frequently do you plan to save these buffers?  If it's pretty infrequent, you could probably just switch manually to the relevant window and `C-x C-w` (or whatever binding you use).  Otherwise, I defer to helm users.